# Ansible nested braces or nested quotes

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, ansible-2.x

Using ansible 2.9 I set a variable like this to store part of a group name

```
  - name: set group
    set_fact:
      ansible_group: aaaa
```

I then want to use this variable in the following `with_items` clause:

```
  - name: get
    uri:
      url: "http://{{ item }}:5324/kjhfg"
    with_items: "{{ groups['thisgroup_{{ ansible_group }}'] }}"
```

However, using nested curly braces gives me the following error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'thisgroup_{{ ansible_group }}'"}
```

I also tried the following syntax variations

```
with_items: "{{ groups['thisgroup_ansible_group'] }}"
with_items: "groups['thisgroup_{{ ansible_group }}']"
with_items: "{{ groups['thisgroup_hostvars['localhost']['ansible_group']'] }}"
with_items: "{{ groups['thisgroup_hostvars[''localhost''][''ansible_group'']'] }}"
with_items: "{{ groups['thisgroup_hostvars[`localhost`][`ansible_group`]'] }}"
```

and probably one hundred other variations which all of them produced various errors

Can someone help me figure out the right syntax?

Comment: I just learned about another notation to address groupvars: `"{{ groups.thisgroup_hostvars['localhost']['ansible_group'] }}"` but that didn't work either

Comment: Avoid naming your variables starting *ansible_*. You can create collisions with [Ansible special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables).

Comment: Since `ansible_group` is a variable, it does NOT go in quotes.  So like this: `{{ groups.thisgroup_hostvars['localhost'][ansible_group] }}`

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate the name of the group, e.g. given the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
[thisgroup_aaaa]
host1
host2
host3
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_group: aaaa
    _group: "{{ groups['thisgroup_' ~ ansible_group] }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ _group }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  item: host1
  item: host2
  item: host3
```